# Using jqGrid on IIS7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, jqgrid

I have jqGrid running fine locally in VS 2008 in a ASP.NET MVC project. When I upload the project to the server (W2008, IIS7) I get an error in IE 8, Object doesn't support this property or method on the call to jqGrid. In Firebug -  jqGrid is not a function. All other JQuery plugins works fine (before and after the upload). Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Is it possible to share the non working page url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem was with the var pathtojsfiles in the jquery.jqGrid.js file. /scripts/js/ works fine locally, but on the server I had to use the full path http://servername/project/Scripts/js/"

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem with JQGrid on IIS7.5 where the columns were displaying but there was no data in the grid. Changing the app pool of the application to the classic app pool fixed this..bit of a weird one.